# Get function timings in pgAdminIII

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'd like to compare two functions in pgAdmin's SQL editor. Here's the script. However, when I run it, seems the `start_time` and `end_time` have the same value no matter how many iterations. (But, the `Query returned successfully with no result in nnn ms.` message does go higher with every increase in the loop size.) Why?

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  start_time timestamp;
  end_time timestamp;
  diff interval;
BEGIN
 SELECT now() INTO start_time;
 FOR i IN 1..1000 LOOP
   --PERFORM uuid_generate_v1mc();
   PERFORM id_generator();
 END LOOP;
 SELECT now() INTO end_time;
 SELECT end_time - start_time INTO diff;
 RAISE NOTICE '%', start_time;
 RAISE NOTICE '%', end_time; 
 RAISE NOTICE '%', diff; 
END
$$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)

> Since these functions *[CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_DATE]* return the start time of the current transaction, **their values do not change during the transaction**.

And then further down:

> `transaction_timestamp()` is equivalent to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, but is named to clearly reflect what it returns. `statement_timestamp()` returns the start time of the current statement (more specifically, the time of receipt of the latest command message from the client). `statement_timestamp()` and `transaction_timestamp()` return the same value during the first command of a transaction, but might differ during subsequent commands. `clock_timestamp()` returns the actual current time, and therefore its value changes even within a single SQL command

So you probably want to use `clock_timestamp()`

Comment: And the bit that actually makes this relevant (from the same doc link): 
``now()`` ``Current date and time (start of current transaction);``
Thanks, I thought ``now()`` was now.

Comment: So, in pgAdmin, the whole script is wrapped in a transaction? Good to know.